# Select multiple values from XML in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have a `@MyXMLString` parameter being passed to a stored procedure in the following format:

```
DECLARE @MyXMLString XML
SET @MyXMLString =
'<data formID="2">
 <UnAssigned AcctTypeID="1"/><UnAssigned AcctTypeID="2"/>
 </data>'
```

In the stored procedure, I have to retrieve the value of `formID` and `AcctTypeID` and then update a table.

Now there will be only one `formID`, which I am able to retrieve

```
DECLARE @formID int
SET @formID = @MyXMLString.value('(data/@formID)[1]','int')
```

But there can be one or multiple `AcctTypeID`, i.e. one or more of `'<UnAssigned AcctTypeID="1"/>'`. I need help in figuring out how to retrieve it.

Answer (score 3):

You can fetch all instances of `AcctTypeID` like this:

```
SELECT 
    XC.value('@AcctTypeID', 'int')
FROM
    @MyXMLString.nodes('/data/UnAssigned') AS XT(XC)
```

When you execute this, these are the results:

[image]

Comment: It is returning two rows of NULL and not getting actual values of AcctTypeID.

Comment: @SilverFish: then you haven't showed us the actual XML that you're getting - with the XML you've posted, this code **works** .... Also: be careful, XML processing is **case sensitive!** Make sure to have all element and/or attribute names cased correctly !

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
DECLARE @MyXMLString XML
SET @MyXMLString =
'<data formID="2">
 <UnAssigned AcctTypeID="1"/><UnAssigned AcctTypeID="2"/>
 </data>'

SELECT X.value('../@formID', 'int') FormID, X.value('@AcctTypeID', 'int') AcctTypeID
FROM @MyXMLString.nodes('data/UnAssigned') T(X)
```

**Result**

```
FormID      AcctTypeID
----------- -----------
2           1
2           2
```